# undefined method `humanize' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know i should put the if statement but how do i have to put. I am new to rails. Can someone figure it out for me ?

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <h4><i><%=@prospects.length.to_s + " " %></i>
            <%= params[:state].humanize.pluralize + " on"%><i><%= @title %></i></h4>
        </div>
        <%= render "admin/report/appointments/filter_form.html.erb" %>
      </div>
```

Comment: Check if params[:state] is present before you apply .humanize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use try block instead of if condition , you can find out more about try from here https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try

rails 5

```
params[:state]&.humanize&.pluralize
```

rails 4

```
params[:state].try(:humanize).try(:pluralize)
```

if you don't want to use try and just want to use if you can use ternary condition

```
<h4><i><%=@prospects.length.to_s + " " %></i> <%= params[:state].nil? ? params[:state] : params[:state].humanize.pluralize "on" %>
```

But try block will do same work of your if condition

Comment: You can say thanks by upvoting and accepting this answer, so it will help other users :)

Comment: yes. will do that. But currently i have to wait for 4mins to accept the answer :D

Comment: Okay no problem, waiting ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <h4><i><%=@prospects.length.to_s + " " %></i>
        <%= params[:state].present? ? params[:state].humanize.pluralize : "" + " on"%><i><%= @title %></i></h4>
    </div>
    <%= render "admin/report/appointments/filter_form.html.erb" %>
</div>
```

I would suggest not to use params directly in views, you can use instance variables or an object if it's already present. .present? can be used inline, .nil should be used on objects as it skips cases like **" ".nil? gives false**